# Trouble including objective c code in an old c header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header, compilation

This is mostly an xcode question. 
I have an objective-c header with an small protocol definition and a seperate C function declaration. I wanted to merge those few header declarations into a larger file that was previously all C code but the xcode compiler is complaining. 
It seems like it should be possible since the original file which included these declarations was also a .h file. Is there a compiler flag I should flip to get my old header recognized as an objective C header?

The problem is, when I include the old header with the objective C code I get an error on the parts that are objective C (the @protocol and @end pieces specifically). I would like to get around this error without moving the objective C code out of the old header.

```
@protocol ConnectorDelegate

-(void)connectorDidReturnValue:(int)value;
@end

initializeConnector(id<ConnectorDelegate> delegate);
```

I get "Expected identifier or '('" at the @protocol and @end parts.

Comment: What is the "complaint"?  Please provide some actual information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could ask why you would want to do this in a C environment (perhaps you're moving to Objective-C?), but I'll instead center on getting rid of your errors so you can move forward.

While you may be working in a header file, it's still being included for a C source file. C knows nothing of protocols; they're the province of Objective-C.

Given that Objective-C is a superset of C, you should be able to change the extension of the file that is including this header from .c to .m with no ill effects, and it should get rid of the compiler errors.

**EDIT**

You can also frame your protocol declaration with `#ifdef __objc__` and `#endif`; this would pre-empt having to change the extensions of your .c files.

Comment: I am getting the error in a .h file because of the Objective-C code included in that file.
When I create a new object in xcode I get a .h and .m pair and there doesn't seem to be a problem with objective-C code in the .h file in that case. It makes me thing xcode is treating the two .h files differently.

Comment: Right. And you're including that file in a .c file, aren't you?

Comment: I'm including it in a .m file.

Comment: Actually, multiple files, some of which are .m and others are .c

Comment: Since objective C is a superset of C couldn't I tell xcode to treat the C files that included the problem header as Objective C files?

Comment: See my edit. I included a tip for a compiler directive. Apologies for not having thought of it sooner.

Comment: The __objc__ ifdef allowed the compilation to go through. I'm going to accept the answer.
Did you find that in the apple docs somewhere?

Comment: No, it's just that I remembered the form used in pre-compiled (.pch) header files. If your project has one, you can see it in action there. But I'm curious too; I'll leave another comment if I find the doc that describes it.